# Excel to csv conversion not showing Char “N/A”

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio-code

I am using pandas to convert excel to a csv file but Getting a blank instead of character “N/A”
How shall I modify my code to get “N/A” without using any other library.

```css
def upload_file_to_directory_bulk(FileUploadName,df):
    try:
        dest_file_client = dest_directory_client.get_file_client(FileUploadName)
        file_contents = df.to_csv(sep = "\t", encoding = "UTF-8", header = None, index = False, line_terminator='\r\n')
        dest_file_client.upload_data(file_contents, overwrite = True)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Comment: where is your code? and an example of the input data?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.